# what does Mrs. Clinton's "deplorables" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

On social media websites, President Trump as well as his supporters refer to themselves as "deplorables" as in:

> We, deplorables, love you Mr. President".

I came to know the word had been first used by Mrs. Clinton to disparagingly refer to Trump's supporters. Meriam Webster lists two meanings for the adjective *deplorable*:

> 1.Deserving censure or contempt.
>
> 2.Lamentable.

So did Mrs. Clinton mean that Trump's supporters were "very bad and so deserve to be rebuked" or that "their ideas and behaviour causes sorrow and so they are truly pathetic"?

Comment: The adjective is being nominalized there, deplorably, as a plural.  Like "the untouchables".

Answer (score 3):

The original quote from Mrs. Clinton was:

> We are living in a volatile political environment. You know, to just be grossly generalistic, **you could put half of Trump's supporters into what I call the basket of deplorables**. Right? The racist, sexist, homophobic, xenophobic, Islamaphobic -- you name it. And unfortunately there are people like that.
>   <sub>([Source: In Context: Hillary Clinton and the 'basket of deplorables' from http://www.politifact.com/](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2016/sep/11/context-hillary-clinton-basket-deplorables/))</sub>

She goes on to say:

> "**But the other basket** [...] of people are people who feel that the government has let them down, the economy has let them down, nobody cares about them, nobody worries about what happens to their lives and their futures, and they're just desperate for change. It doesn't really even matter where it comes from. They don't buy everything he says, but he seems to hold out some hope that their lives will be different. They won't wake up and see their jobs disappear, lose a kid to heroin, feel like they're in a dead-end. **Those are people we have to understand and empathize with** as well."

So, essentially she was categorizing Trump's supporters into two "baskets" the irredeemable "deplorables" and the "others" who she wanted her supporters to try to persuade to vote for her instead of Trump.

Calling yourself "a deplorable" is a way of stating that you strongly support Trump, and strongly dislike Clinton. You're saying that you are in the first "basket" of Trump supporters that couldn't be persuaded to vote for Clinton under any circumstances. Just to be clear, most of the people who are calling themselves "deplorables" don't actually believe that they are any of the things Mrs. Clinton listed. They are in a way mocking Mrs. Clinton by being proud to be "a deplorable".